# What does 'Please download the latest app' mean when running the simulator?

Tags: react-native

After running `yarn start && yarn ios` on a React Native project, the simulator shows this screen. What causes this to appear?

[image]

Comment: Is this happening on android as well?

Comment: This sounds like it's part of the project rather than React Native